# How to ensure my init is called for a subclass?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to override the init for the class UITextView

There are two init methods of that class, and my init has to call one of those 2

```
init?(coder: NSCoder)

init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)
```

But I want to write some setup code for my subclass that is always called no matter which init is used. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

subclass both init methods and do in there whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)

        customSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        customSetup()
    }

    private func customSetup() {

        //any custom methods you need
    }
}
```

You just `override` the initializers, and call the superclass' initializers, then add your custom class' initialization code after that.